# Trigger.io error "/usr/bin/codesign no identity found" can't create package or run the app on the device

Tags: trigger.io

I have a problem when trying to run my application on the device or create IPA file.

I followed the steps [here](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/best_practice/release_mobile.html#creating-provisioning-profiles) and I have this error when trying to run on iOS option:

```
[ERROR] Failed when running /usr/bin/codesign: FdawaDev: no identity found
```

I tried to make it throw terminal with this command

```
forge package ios --ios.profile.provisioning_profile Development.mobileprovision
```

and I'm getting this error

```
    /Applications/TriggerToolkit.app/Contents/MacOS/forge -v package ios --ios.profile.provisioning_profile Development.mobileprovision
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.43
[  DEBUG] Checking for update zip...
[  ERROR] Couldn't import generation code: No module named generate_dynamic
[  DEBUG] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/TriggerToolkit.app/Contents/MacOS/build-tools/forge/async.py", line 98, in run
    result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Applications/TriggerToolkit.app/Contents/MacOS/build-tools/forge/main.py", line 443, in package
    generate_dynamic = forge_build.import_generate_dynamic()
  File "/Applications/TriggerToolkit.app/Contents/MacOS/build-tools/forge/build.py", line 67, in import_generate_dynamic
    raise ForgeError("Couldn't import generation code: {0}".format(e))
ForgeError: Couldn't import generation code: No module named generate_dynamic
```

I removed TriggerToolkit and download the latest one, installed it again and I'm still getting the same error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is a configuration problem: you're pointing at an iOS developer identity called "FdawaDev" when one doesn't exist in your Keychain.

Unless you have several identities, you can safely leave the "Certificate" Local Config setting empty in the Toolkit.

If you have several identities, you should specify one with something like `iPhone Developer: James Brady`.

For the second problem, when using the command line tools, you have to manually run a build before doing a run or package action, e.g.:

```
% forge build ios && forge package ios
```

Comment: i have only one identity and why there is no video talking about this important thing ! if you have any video talking about releasing our app please provide it also i tried the command again with the new args and this is the result 

================================================
File "/Users/dahabit/forge-workspace/fdawa/.template/generate_dynamic/build.py", line 76, in _arguments_to_key_values
    raise ArgumentError("Failed to parse command line arguments at {arg}".format(arg=arg))
ArgumentError: Failed to parse command line arguments at Development.mobileprovision

Comment: Sure, for information about the certificate argument, see http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/best_practice/release_mobile.html#ios and http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/tools/local-config.html#ios

Comment: Thanks James , i talked to Amir and he gave me the video link :)

and the problem solved

Comment: @JamesBrady that link is dead. shame that links to the old docs aren't  redirecting to somewhere useful.